# Hash256 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, hash

In Java I generate an hashing of a value `X` using the Apache Commons Codec library:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

String agId = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(X)
```

Is there a way to do the same using JavaScript? Are there any library around for do a simple hash256?